# How KYC ICO check addresses during crowdsale?

Tags: contract-development, crowdsale

I see more ICO are complying with KYC. I wonder what exactly means for the crowdsale smart contract. Is the latter rejecting eth coming from unregistered addresses? Then, how is this managed? With a huge table inside the crowdsale?

Thx for any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's what it usually is. If you check the source of the [Raiden crowdsale contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb5e5585d0057501c91c48094029a6f4fb10b5a01#code), what you're looking for is the functionality around the array `whitelist`, as that is where they stored their KYC verified contributors.